# how to do dynamic drop down list in <td> html (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ive trying to add a dynamic drop down list in the `td`.

```html
<td>
  <input list="parameters" name="health_parameter" class="form-control textclass" 
        t-att-value="vi.parameter_id.parameter_name" readonly="true">                                                                      
     <datalist id="parameters">                                                                                      
       <t t-foreach="health_parameter" t-as="parameter" t-att-value="parameter.id" >                                                                                        
         <option  t-att-value="parameter.id">                                                                                           
           <t t-esc ="parameter.parameter_name"/>                                                                                      
         </option>                                                                                      
       </t>                                                                                  
     </datalist>                                                                               
  </input>                                                                           
</td>
```

health_parameter is the variable having the datas, I need to listout the datas from the 'health_parameter' dynamically to the dropdown list and the user have to select and update.
(is there any method to get input type as select?)

Comment: can you explain more on your issue ?

Comment: @swati Ive sorted the issue, the issue was about not getting the values from the controller.py